# calculating shipping rates based on additional weight

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am currently designing database for making invoices for shipping company.
The point where i stuck is how to calculate rates which exceeds wight limit.

I have one table called tblRates
columns {id,from_weight,to_wight,price}
rows would be like

```
[{1,0,499,20$},
 {2,500,1999,40$}, //max weight 2Kg
 {3,2000,'unlimited','$20'}] //this row holds pricing for every add 500gm
```

as you can see i can easily get rates upto 2kg just by using between query. But when weight exceeds 2kg i want to break it into slice of 500gm and charge 20 bucks for each slice. e.g. if weight is 3300, price will be $40 + $(3 * 20). dont worry about location based pricing. its just for simplicity to understand my question i moved price into this table. its just how to determine the slices when given weight exceeds limit.

//wip sp

```
CREATE Procedure Sic.getRates
@Weight Decimal(7,3),
AS
 BEGIN
    SELECT Price 
      FROM tblRates
     WHERE @weight BETWEEN from_rates  AND to_rates;
 END
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Most dbms products have their own, non-ANSI SQL compliant stored procedures.)

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: i am currently using MS sql.

Comment: currently i have not designed table yet. it is like how i can structure those rates for exceeded limits, and can calculate additional slices

Comment: updated my post. its just blur idea. my main focus on getting those count of slices which exceeds limits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/127b8/31

```
Create Table tblRates(
  id int,
  from_weight int,
  to_wight int,
  base_price int,
  extra_price_per_500_g int
);

Insert Into tblRates (id,from_weight,to_wight,base_price,extra_price_per_500_g)
Values
(1,0,499,20,0),
(2,500,1999,40,0),
(3,2000,2147483647,40,20);

Declare @Weight int = 3300

Select 
  base_price + extra_price_per_500_g * CEILING((@Weight - from_weight)/500.0) price
From
  tblRates
Where 
  @Weight BETWEEN from_weight AND to_wight;
```

I redesigned your table, and changed `@Weight Decimal(7,3)` to `@Weight int` (or, you will have a problem with using between; try @Weight = 1999.06 to see the mistake).